# Go to another html file via JS

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have an

```
<a href= ./index2.html>
```

button in my index.html but now I want to change it so it also calls a function when it gets clicked, so I tried

```
<a href="./index2.html;javascript:randomFunction();"
```

but it doesn't work, how can I make an  element make switch html page and call a function at once? Thanks!!

Comment: in `index2.html` You'd need to have `randomFunction` in a `window.onload` like so: `window.onload = function()
                {
                   randomFunction();
                };`

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that you want to run the JS on the current page:**

The quick and dirty method that you shouldn't use is to add an `onclick` attribute.

```
<a href="index2.html" onclick="randomFunction()">
```

The clean approach is to [bind an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) with JS.

```
reference_to_anchor.addEventListener('click', randomFunction);
```

(See the documentation linked above for details, and for work arounds to lack of support in older versions of IE).

(See also [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

This will run the JavaScript on the page on which the link appears before the link is followed.

**If, on the other hand, you want the JavaScript to run on the destination page:**

You have a rather more complicated problem to deal with.

A new page means a new execution environment. Client side code on one page can't trigger client side code on the next.

I'd approach *that* problem by having a server side script generate `index2` and include `<script>randomFunction();</script>` if a particular query string was present on the URI.

Comment: Thats ok if they want the js to run before the page navigates. What if they want it to run after navigation?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko — I was typing that as you commented.

Answer (score 0):

make it call the desired function via `onclick` event, at the end of the function do a:

```
window.location=url;
```

or if you want to change page and then call a function on the new one use a normal `a` tag to go to the new page, then:

```
window.onload=function(){
     //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="javascript:randomFunction()"`

For instance:

```
<a href="./index2.html" onclick="randomFunction()">
```

Comment: Why have you included a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in the onclick attribute? There is no loop to `break` or `continue` from.

Comment: @Quentin copy-paste error :) I just edited OP's code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use onclick event to call a function

```
<a href="index2.html" onclick="javascript:randomFunction();"></a>
```

Comment: Why have you included a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in the onclick attribute? There is no loop to `break` or `continue` from.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onclick` event of javascript.

```
<a href="./index2.html" onclick="return randomFunction();"></a> 

function randomFunction(){
   // do needfull code here.
}
```